# sqlite - how can I know Oldest items do not use

Tags: sqlite

how can I find "Oldest items do not use"

I'm developing something using sqlite3 library.
making table and inserting... are done.

for example,
table shape is like below. the meaning is not important.
the key is id, and each id have x position and y position. that's all.

```
id   -   position x   -   position y
ab   -      10        -       44
cd   -      48        -       55
ef   -      97        -       11
```

I added upper items each different time.
and I can read x and y anytime.

in this case, if I want to delete the oldest items do not use(same as "read").
how can I know?(which api can I use?)

Comment: the example is poor... just 3x3 table...

Comment: What do you mean with "oldest"? There is no such information in the example data you've shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to infer the age of a record for use in a DELETE statement's where-clause, you need to have set up a datetime column beforehand, and made sure to populate it correctly on each insert (and update if applicable). Preferably using UTC time to avoid timezone headaches.

(As a practice, I usually set up "DateCreated" "DateModified" columns on all significant tables, even if the data is not immediately useful.)

Comment: the conclusion is... I need to add time column... thanks^^